# Call Zend FlashMessanger from my custom library

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-studio

I've searched the web but couldn't find any example, so maybe you know if it's possible and whether it is a good idea.

I wrote a function `adminloginCheck()` that is located in `library/myNameSpace/LoginCheck.php`

I moved the code I had inside the `preDispatch()` of my Controller and inside `preDispatch()` I'm calling `$mynamespace->adminloginCheck();`

in my `predispatch()` I had a FlashMessanger `$this->_helper->FlashMessenger($message);`

but it looks like (and for sure it wouldn't) `$this->_helper->FlashMessenger($message)` doesn't work in my own class - `library/myNameSpace/LoginCheck.php`

So my question is - how to call `FlashMessenger` from outside the controller, in my own class.

I'm calling `$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();` directly in there. So how to do the same thing with FlashMessanger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$messenger = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger();
$messenger->addMessage('hello');
$messages = $messenger->getMessages();
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered that, and came back here to edit my question. Thanks for attention mate! Maybe it will help someone